# Why Hyde Park become Haido Park?

Tags: detective-conan

I've read this Detective Conan manga Chapter 499-504 there's a case when Conan chasing Rena Mizunashi,
the CIA agent that disguise as Black Organization member with code name Kir.
She along with Korn and Chianti is assigned to kill Mayor Candidate (I don't remember his name).

In that time, Conan's tracker is stick to Kir's shoes and he heard the code about the place
where the Black Organization plan to Kill the Mayor.

Conan realize that the place is Hyde Park, and he said it's not really Hyde Park that located in London but in Haido Park.
But I'm still not understand why can Hayde Park become Haido Park, is anyone can explain about this?

Comment: Haido is how Japanese pronounce Hyde.

Comment: Please specify the source of your manga. Third party scanlation typically don't transliterate names properly.

Comment: @ʇosɥıuonʞʎonʞo already updated my question, it's around chapter 499 - 403

Comment: @SakuraiTomoko eh? so it's more like a pun?

Comment: @JTR Yup. See Michael McQuade's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll be basing my answer off the anime adaption of these chapters, which took place in episode 425.

There were three possible victims this time, all of them were candidates for the House of Representatives in Japan. This number is based off the fact that there would be three interviews. The letters "DJ" were overheard as the target and the place they overheard for this murder was "Eddie P."

When Haibara is asked what Eddie P is she states that P means that it is a park.

Later, Conan gets a call from Ran and answers in his normal Conan facade. Jodie notices this and calls him out on it saying that he has a double personality:
[image: Oh, Cool Kid, you have a totally double personality.]

This triggers Conan to think about the following clues:

- Hunting Ground
- History
- Park
- Double Personality

Besides history, which is just something Vermouth mentioned as this is an old story, these clues are all elements of the Jekyll & Hyde story; from these clues Conan remembers the scene of Mouri Kogoro flipping through the Jekyll & Hyde book.

The closest you can transliterate Jekyll & Hyde in Japanese Katakana is ジキルとハイド. ハイド can be wrote in Romaji as Haido (it's also the way it is pronounced). From here Conan concludes that it must be Haido park and they manage to get there before the camera crew.

Answer (score 0):

Names of towns and streets in *Detective Conan* are excerpts from actual names of places and streets in London or the UK in general.

Haido park, once translated into properly pronounced English is going to be Hyde park which is an actual park in London. Another example is Beika street, once also translated into properly pronounced english is going to be Baker street which is a street in the UK and also the same street Sherlock Holmes lived in.